# Countdown timer: need timer to automatically start from 3:00 after reaching 0 minutes for infinite times

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, css

Need a countdown timer that will start from 03:00,02:59... once it reaches 0:00, timer should automatically reset to 03:00 and this logic should be infinite. Just assume that Noone should have any control over this logic to stop it. 
i browsed and went through a javascript code. Incase of using only Javascript features, if the enduser trigger's browser refresh then the counter resets to 3:00. This should not happen.
 So i'm using JS,Jquery,PHP, Mysql with hope that i can find solutions by keeping starttime,endtime,Intreval Duration in Database(Sorry for not elaborating but i assume that this is a common usecase and people can understand what i'm facing here). 
I'm still looking for solutions. kindly help me out with this.

BTW, i'm not looking out answers for Countdowntimer problem, once timer gets to 0:00 job's done for countdown timer. i have idea's for it.

Comment: Wait, so you're asking, if the timer is at, say, 1:45 and the page is refreshed, it should start up again at 1:45?

Comment: @P.Gearman it should be 1:44 or 1:43 depending on internet speed. it should not stay at 1:45 when it is refreshed at 1:45

Comment: Normally you do this by saving a time in a database somewhere.

Comment: Should probably use a session variable to store the value.

Comment: @tadman yes. For countdown timer thats fine. But my requirement is, once timer gets to 0:00, automatically the process should repeat to 3:00

Comment: That's an interesting problem, but the first question you need to answer here is "What have you tried?" Triggering an AJAX call every N seconds isn't that tricky.

Comment: @tadman everytime i can trigger ajax req for every second. For every ajax request i possibly need to open a db connection, to check for timestamp and if the timestamp difference gets to 0:00 in DB then  i need to update the record to new start and endtime. There are many users for this website. I'm not sure whether this is the right way to proceed. If mysql db automatically updates the start,end time for every 3 minute interval it should make few things easier (I'm just saying this). I'm looking for possible solutions.

Comment: Every second is going to be murder on your server. Doing it when the time runs out is probably sufficient, and if the page gets reloaded, fetch the time remaining from the last counter and start there.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the inputs. i will check it. if any other, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer by this way-

```js
// 15 days from now!
var date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$('#clock').countdown(date, function(event)
{
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,600,300italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/css/syntax.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/css/main.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.1.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div class="example-base">
  Limited Time Only!
  <span id="clock"></span>
</div>
```

Now what u need to do is integrate it with PHP.

When the page loaded, u have to [**set timeouts**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for the JS code.

So, then JS code would be like this-

```
setTimeout( function()
{
    //JS code for timer 
    var date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $('#clock').countdown(date, function(event)
    {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
}  , 1000 );
```

Here time is set to 1 second, but in your case, time should come from server, so what you should do is something like this in PHP to get seconds remaining-

```
$timeCurrent  = strtotime('now');
$timeFutre = strtotime(date("Y-m-d").' 03:00:00');
$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
```

Now u should use it in JS.

U either can use AJAX and set the time remaing or can just use PHP echo like this-

```
setTimeout( function()
{
    //JS code for timer 
    var date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $('#clock').countdown(date, function(event)
    {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
}  , 1000* <?php
                $timeCurrent  = strtotime('now');
                $timeFutre = strtotime(date("Y-m-d").' 03:00:00');
                $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
                echo $differenceInSeconds; 
           ?> );
```

Think you have your complete answer.